# SQL server 2012 returns different results than SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a piece of script using cursor to sequence rows in a table. For example, the table looks like this,
SSN, Kid_SSN, Kid_DOB, Seq# to list every person with 1 or more kids. I want to update Seq# to label each kid as 1,2,3... based on Date Of Birth.
I used cursor for update to get it done successfully in SQL server 2008. My current trouble is that this same script wouldn't run as expected in sql server 2012. The problem is in SQL 2012 cursor fetch NEXT more than 1 row at a time. So question is where can I set the cursor fetch size? I searched around but came up no good answer.
Anyone here can shed some light? thanks.

Scrip looks like this:

```
DECLARE @SocialSecurity varchar(9), @PersonID int, @Dep_SSN varchar(9)
DECLARE @LastName varchar(20), @FirstName varchar(20), @BirthDate datetime, 
    @Number int

DECLARE @ssn varchar(9) = '000000000'
DECLARE @Mem int = 1
DECLARE cur cursor
FOR SELECT * FROM kids
FOR UPDATE OF Number;

OPEN cur;

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @SocialSecurity, @PersonID, @Dep_SSN, @LastName, @FirstName, 
    @BirthDate, @Number;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

IF @SocialSecurity = @ssn
BEGIN

UPDATE kids
SET Number = @Mem+1
WHERE CURRENT OF cur
SET @Mem = @Mem+1
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @ssn = @SocialSecurity
SET @Mem = 1
END;
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @SocialSecurity, @PersonID, @Dep_SSN, @LastName, @FirstName, 
    @BirthDate, @Number;
END;
CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
```

More info on this problem.
kids is a temp table generated by 'SELECT .. INTO' and a simplified set looks like this

```
SSN       Kid_SSN        DOB        Seq#
123123123 987987987      1/1/2000   1
123123123 987987988      1/1/2003   1
123123125 890890890      2/3/2002   1
```

So all seq# are initiated to 1. After going through the script above, I expect table kids to
look like this

```
SSN       Kid_SSN        DOB        Seq#
123123123 987987987      1/1/2000   1
123123123 987987988      1/1/2003   2
123123125 890890890      2/3/2002   1
```

The script ran perfectly to achieve this on server 2008 R2, but not on server 2012. Furthermore, I found that it only updated row 88, 176 and so on, if applicable. That is why I think cursor fetch 88 rows at a time. But on server 2008 it apparently fetch 1 row at a time as I expected. Hope this will explain the problem I have. 
I want to force cursor fetching 1 row at a time to make it work on server 2012, though it's not efficient. Or, how to do sequencing without using cursor? Thanks.

Comment: Does `kids` have a primary key? I think there is a MUCH more efficient way to write this query in about one line, and there is certainly a better way to write the cursor if you really want to stay with a cursor for some reason. Also, what kind of predictable result do you expect from your cursor? You didn't bother specifying an ORDER BY!

Comment: I'm with @AaronBertrand here, don't understand how that ever worked, unless it was basically down to luck. All my cursors when straight across from 2008 to 2012 with no issues. I'm certain fetch next is not fetching two records, it's just not fetching them in the order it used to.

Comment: Finally, do you plan to run this cursor across the entire table after every insert/update/delete? Since your "numbers" will get all messed up if, say, you are sorting by DOB and an older/younger kid joins. Much better to derive this result in a query than to store it, if all it is is some meaningless rank. If the numbers mean something, then describe what that is. As Tony suggested, this is not fetching the wrong number of rows, it's just not fetching in the order you probably expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would it work to replace the entire script with a rank over function?

Something like

```
select *, rank() over (partition by SSN, Kid_DOB order by Kid_SSN) as SeqNum
from kids
```

I think this should work and if not you can tweak the partition and order by to make it work.

Comment: Maybe select *, rank() over (partition by SSN order by Kid_DOB) as SeqNum from kids

Comment: Fantastic, work perfectly. Thank you so much. I learned a new trick, and don't have to bother cursor for this.

Answer (score 1):

Your script requires that the cursor on `kids` groups records by the same SSN. But there is no ORDER BY to enforce this. Thus the records are being returned in some random order which messes up the `@Mem` counter.

It's not an issue with SQL 2012 vs. 2008. I believe you simply lucked out with SQL 2008 and the records were already ordered the way you wanted them, or SQL 2008 has a different behavior for selecting unordered results, or you defined the pk and indexes differently.